# Выделение памяти: new vs Foo{}

Tags: golang, структуры

В чём разница между созданием структуры через new, и через имя структуры + фигурные скобки (не знаю как правильно назвать такой способ инициализации)?

```
type Foo struct {
    X int
}

f1 := &Foo{}
f2 := new(Foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Эти две конструкции ничем не различаются, в обоих случаях создается элемент Foo и возвращается указатель *Foo на вновь созданный элемент. Только в первом случае можно еще указывать параметры f1 := &Foo{100}. Зачем нужны два одинаковых метода? Первый & является частью указателей и применяется для операций с ними, второй для явного создания пустого объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Тем что в одном случае Вы в явном виде создаете в куче. А в другом случае даете простор для оптимизационных размышлений компилятору и возможность выбора между кучей и стеком, когда выгоден тот или иной случай